# Laravel reponse does not contain Set-Cookie header

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I have a **Laravel** API that uses passport, what i need is to set the access to the Set-Cookie header, but the problem is it that my response does not contain any, and i having this warning 'Provisional headers are shown in my request headers.

im using *HttpClient* in angular to request for the data

**This is the response that should contain a cookie**

```
return response()->json([
 "status" => "ok",
 "message" => "good to go"
])->cookie('test','sampledata');
```

**this is the RESPONSE Header im getting**

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 11 Mar 2019 12:12:13 +0000, Mon, 11 Mar 2019 12:12:13 GMT
Host: localhost:8080
Vary: Origin
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.11
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes in your `api` middleware group are stateless and do not run the session or cookie middleware. If you need a route that sets cookies, your best option is to define it in `routes/web.php` instead.

Comment: so the ''Provisional headers are shown" warning has nothing to with the response?